# Loading a page in a div via clicking a link not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, load

The following way of loading a page in a div via clicking a link works with all browsers but with Safari.

Can anyone please give me a clue on what is Safari choking on?

Thanks a lot!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

              $("#fs").click(function(eventt){
              $("#adiv").html('<div id="destiny"></div>');

                  fs();
              });

    })    

            function fs() {   

              $("#destiny").load("mypage.php", {}, function(){  });
            }  

    </script>

 <a href="#" id="fs">Click me</a> 
 <div id="adiv"></div>
```

Comment: do you have #adiv element? and if you don't have any other parameters you can just do $("#adiv").load("mypage.php")

Comment: tried, but didn't make a diference :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simplifying your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#fs").click(fs);

   function fs() {   
      $("#adiv").html('<div id="destiny"></div>');
      $("#destiny").load("mypage.php");
   }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks but cannot do that, inside of   $("#fs").click(function(eventt){
 there's   $("#anotherdiv").html('<div id="addeddiv"></div>'); Sorry I omited it

Comment: maybe thats the problem. can you please try posting more of your code ?

Comment: I've updated my reply. you can move your div creation inside `fs()`

Comment: Why did it work? I can't seem to find any effective difference.

Comment: Can't really say without looking at the full code. Moved the fs method inside the document.ready scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work better when you replace .html with below code

```
.ajaxComplete(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {

        });
```

**Old code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#fs").click(function(event){
          $("#content").html('<div id="content"></div>');
              fs();
          });
})    
        function Diensten() {   
          $("#content").load("test.php", {}, function(){  });
        }  
</script>
```

**New Code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#Diensten").click(function(event){
          $("#content").ajaxComplete(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) {

        });('<div id="content"></div>');
              Diensten();
          });
})    
        function Diensten() {   
          $("#content").load("diensten.php", {}, function(){  });
        }  
</script>
```